# Codeigniter - Shopping Cart: Won't let me get hidden field Row IDs

Tags: php, codeigniter, shopping-cart

I'm trying to get edit functionality on my Shopping cart.
I want it to be basically go to a page called users/view_cart, then the user selects whether they are only updating the cart(changing quantities) or are checking out (purchasing through a transaction).

I'm following the display the cart page provided at this location:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/cart.html

```
public function view_cart(){
    $this->load->model('purchases_model');
    $this->load->model('transactions_model');

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('action', 'action', 'required');

    $num = $this->cart->total_items();

    for($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($i.'[qty]',
                                'Quantity of the '.$i.'th element of the cart',
                                            'required');

    }

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
        $data['title'] = 'View your cart!';
        $this->load->view('templates/LI_header', $data);    
        $this->load->view('users/view_cart');
        $this->load->view('templates/LI_footer');
    } elseif($this->input->post('action') == 'checkout') {
        $data['title'] = 'Buy cart!';
        $id = $this->session->userdata('uid');
        $transactionsData = array(
                                'amount' => $this->cart->format_number($this->cart->total())
                                );  
        $tid = $this->transactions_model->insert($transactionsData);

        foreach($this->cart->contents() as $items){
            $wsid = $items['id'];
            $purchaseData = array(
                                'wsid'  =>  $wsid,
                                'uid'   =>  $id,
                                'tid'   =>  $tid
                                );
            $this->purchases_model->insert($purchaseData);
        }

        $this->load->view('templates/LI_header', $data);    
        $this->load->view('users/buy_cart_success');
        $this->load->view('templates/LI_footer');
        $this->cart->destroy();         
    } else {
        $data['title'] = 'Edit Cart!';

        /* Manual input of the rowid and new quantity work
        $cartData = array('rowid' => 'c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b','qty'=>5);
        $this->cart->update($cartData);
        */
        /*
        for($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++){
            $rowid = $this->input->post($i.'[rowid]');
            $newQty = $this->input->post($i.'[qty]');
            $cartData = array(
                            'rowid' => $rowid, 
                            'qty'   => $newQty
                            );
            $this->cart->update($cartData);
        }
        print_r($formData);
        $this->load->view('templates/LI_header', $data);    
        $this->load->view('users/edit_cart_success');
        $this->load->view('templates/LI_footer');
    }
}
```

Start of the view_cart view:

```
<?php echo form_open('users/view_cart'); ?>

<table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%" border="0">

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<tr>
  <th>QTY</th>
  <th>Item Description</th>
  <th style="text-align:right">Item Price</th>
  <th style="text-align:right">Sub-Total</th>
</tr>

<?php $i = 1; ?>

<?php foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items): ?>

    <?php echo form_hidden($i.'[rowid]', $items['rowid']); ?>

    <tr>
      <td><?php echo form_input(array('name' => $i.'[qty]', 'value' => $items['qty'], 'maxlength' => '3', 'size' => '5')); ?></td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $items['name']; ?>

            <?php if ($this->cart->has_options($items['rowid']) == TRUE): ?>

                <p>
                    <?php foreach ($this->cart->product_options($items['rowid']) as $option_name => $option_value): ?>

                        <strong><?php echo $option_name; ?>:</strong> <?php echo $option_value; ?><br />

                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </p>

            <?php endif; ?>

      </td>
      <td style="text-align:right"><?php echo $this->cart->format_number($items['price']); ?></td>
      <td style="text-align:right">$<?php echo $this->cart->format_number($items['subtotal']); ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php $i++; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<tr>
  <td colspan="2"> </td>
  <td class="right"><strong>Total</strong></td>
  <td class="right">$<?php echo $this->cart->format_number($this->cart->total()); ?></td>
</tr>

</table>
</br>
<?php echo form_radio('action','update',FALSE); ?> Update your cart
</br>
<?php echo form_radio('action','checkout', FALSE) ?> Check out your cart
</br>
<p><?php echo form_submit('users/view_cart', 'Process'); ?></p>
```

I tried writing some debugging code but the results I got were inconclusive.
In particular:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($i.'[qty]','Quantity of the '.$i.'th element of the cart','required');
    $formData[$i]['qty']    = $this->input->post(intval($i).'[qty]');
    $formData[$i]['rowid']  = $this->input->post(intval($i).'[rowid]');
    }
    print_r($formData);
```

The above snippet outputs:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [qty] => [rowid] => ) [2] => Array ( [qty] => [rowid] => ) [3] => Array ( [qty] => [rowid] => ) )
```

Which is weird because it seems to map " $i.'[qty]' " from the previous lines to the proper form validations but otherwise doesn't map me the correct data from the hidden fields.

Help, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating array based form names. e.g.

`<input type="hidden" name="1[rowid]" value="1starrthing" />`, causes your hidden form values to show in the post data as a sub array like so:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [rowid] => 1starrthing
        [qty] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [rowid] => 1starrthing222
        [qty] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [rowid] => 1starrthing3333
        [qty] => 1
    )
```

So unless you're going for that, try changing your hidden form name to `rowid[]` which will give you an array of rowids like so:

```
[rowid] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1starrthing
        [1] => 1starrthing222
        [2] => 1starrthing3333
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [qty] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [qty] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [qty] => 1
    )
```

OR prepend your counter to the name like this: `name="rowid_.$i"` which will give you:

```
[rowid_1] => 1starrthing
[1] => Array
    (
        [qty] => 1
    )

[rowid_2] => 1starrthing222
[2] => Array
    (
        [qty] => 1
    )

[rowid_3] => 1starrthing3333
[3] => Array
    (
        [qty] => 1
    )
```

Also, it's likely your values in your hidden inputs are empty unless for some reason your $items array has 'qty' as the key for each item. Try

```
<?php echo form_hidden('rowid[]', $items); ?>
```

For added debugging help, try turning profiling on; this will give you more info on post's/queries and other stuff.

Bottom of view file:

`$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);`

Comment: seems sensible, changing the names seems to allow me to alter the cart. Why are so many of sample code snippets written like this though?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this has anythign to do with it, but in your set_rules, the $i.'[qty]' seems off. If you're trying to reference the key in the array, then it'd need to have quotes inside the brackets, just like your code does later on: i.e. `$i."['qty']"` or something like that? Not sure. Point is, I think that's where the disconnect is in the code.